# What does the IL ".custom instance void [attribute] = (...)" mean?

Tags: c#, parameters, cil

When I used the params keyword for a parameter I found this line in the IL. What I understood from this is that a constructor of the ParamArrayAttribute class is called but I didn't understand what 01 00 00 00 means.

```
.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.ParamArrayAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please refer to section II.21 of the [C# specification (version 6) defined in ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm):

```
Custom attributes are declared using the directive .custom, followed by the method
declaration for a type constructor, optionally followed by a Bytes in parentheses:
CustomDecl ::=
    Ctor [ ‘=’ ‘(’ Bytes ‘)’ ]
```

The format of the `Bytes` segment is defined in section II.23.3:

```
CustomAttrib starts with a Prolog – an unsigned int16, with value 0x0001.
...
Next is a description of the optional “named” fields and properties. This starts with
NumNamed – an unsigned int16 giving the number of “named” properties or fields that
follow. Note that NumNamed shall always be present. A value of zero indicates that there
are no “named” properties or fields to follow (and of course, in this case, the
CustomAttrib shall end immediately after NumNamed).
```

Examples of various custom attributes are provided in section VI.B.3.

In the case of `ParamArrayAttribute`, the first two bytes (`01 00`) are `Prolog` (in little-endian format), and the last two bytes (`00 00`) are `NumNamed` (0 = no arguments).

Answer (score 4):

When used to decorate members, attributes may contain initialization parameters that will be sent to the attribute's constructor.

For Instance

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = true)]
public int Property { get; set; }
```

is compiled to

```
.custom instance void
[System.Runtime.Serialization]System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute::.ctor() = 
( 01 00 01 00 54 02 10 45 6D 69 74 44 65 66 61 75 6C 74 56 61 6C 75 65 01 )
```

The byte code sequence you see corresponds to the initialization of the `EmitDefaultValue` parameter.

In your case,

```
01 00 00 00
```

is the sequence of bytes used when no parameters are passed to the attribute contructor.